# How to loop through plots and tables and knit to PDF in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating a PDF report in R Markdown and I'd like to loop through a series of tables and plots based on a unique value/category in my `activity` column.

My problem is that the number of unique values of `activity` will change from day-to-day and won't always be 10. Sometimes it could be 8, other times it could be 12, for exampple. As a result, I'd like to know how I can use my loop and have the knitted PDF start a new page dynamically when required so a table and accompanying plot don't appear on separate pages as they currently are.

My entire Markdown code is below and the settings I've applied in the YAML are what my final report will use. Currently, my code produces the respective plots and tables in odd orders, whereas I want the table to appear first and the plot directly below (which I thought `print(t)` followed by `print(p)` would achieve.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

````
---
title: >
  `\vspace{-1.8cm}`{=latex}
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{geometry}
 - \geometry{margin=0.2in}
 - \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
 - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 - \usepackage{makecell}
 - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 - \pagestyle{fancy}
 - \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
 - \fancyhf{}
 - \addtolength{\headheight}{3.0cm}
 - \rhead{\Huge\textbf{Test Report}}
 - \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
 - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 - \pagenumbering{gobble}
mainfont: SourceSansPro
output: pdf_document
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

\vspace{-10truemm}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE,
  dev = "cairo_pdf"
  )
```

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
# Datset 1.
dat1 <- data.frame(activity = paste("Activity", 1:10),
                 var1 = rnorm(10, 100, 30),
                 var4 = rnorm(10, 100, 30),
                 var3 = rnorm(10, 100, 30))

# Datset 2.
dat2 <- data.frame(activity = rep(paste("Activity", 1:10), each = 3),
                 met = rep(paste0("var", 1:3), times = 10),
                 pct = sample(1:100, 30))

```

```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=2.5, fig.align='center', results='asis'}
# Loop to print individual tables and plots.
activity_order <- unique(dat1$activity)

for (i in activity_order) {
  
  cat("Activity:", i, "\n")
  
  d1 <- dat1 %>% filter(activity == i) %>% select(-activity)
  d2 <- dat2 %>% filter(activity == i)
  
  t <-kbl(d1,
          booktabs = TRUE,
          escape = FALSE,
          align = "c") %>%
    kable_styling(font_size = 12) %>%
    row_spec(row = 0, background = "black", color = "white", bold = TRUE)
  
  p <- ggplot(d2) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
    geom_col(aes(x = pct, y = met),
             fill = "#ED1B2F", colour = "black", width = 0.6) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(),
          axis.title = element_blank())
  
  print(t)
  print(p)
  cat("\n")
  
  }
```
````